# Create dynamically changing background images with animation

Tags: html, css, animation, background, background-image

I'm trying to create a background image which changes every few seconds with an animation so the next image slides in from the right at the same time as the other image slides out.

Currently I have a code without animation; it works fine, however the images take ages to load. Is this just because my image files are too large? Is there a way to make them load faster?

My current code is:

HTML:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var header = $('body');

    var backgrounds = new Array(
        'url(DSC_0007.jpg)'
      , 'url(DSC_01110.jpg)'
      , 'url(DSC_0277.jpg)'
      , 'url(DSC_0050.jpg)'
    );

    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        current++;
        current = current % backgrounds.length;
        header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
    }
    setInterval(nextBackground, 5000);

    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
    });
    </script>
```

CSS:

```
    body{
      background: url(DSC_0007.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

I'm very new to coding so would appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS `animation`.

```css
img#bg1 {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: background1 60s ease 0s infinite;
}
img#bg2 {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: background2 60s ease 0s infinite;
  margin-left: -100%;
}
img#bg3 {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: background3 60s ease 0s infinite;
  margin-left: -100%;
}
img#bg4 {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: background4 60s ease 0s infinite;
  margin-left: -100%;
}
@keyframes background1 {
  0% { margin-left: -0%; }
  20% { margin-left: -0%; }
  25% { margin-left: 100%; }
  26% { margin-left: -100%; }
  95% { margin-left: -100%; z-index: 1; }
  100% { margin-left: -0%; z-index: 1; }
}
@keyframes background2 {
  0% { margin-left: -100%; }
  20% { margin-left: -100%; }
  25% { margin-left: -0%; }
  45% { margin-left: -0%; }
  50% { margin-left: 100%; }
  100% { margin-left: -0%; }
}
@keyframes background3 {
  0% { margin-left: -100%; }
  45% { margin-left: -100%; }
  50% { margin-left: -0%; }
  70% { margin-left: -0%; }
  75% { margin-left: 100%; }
  100% { margin-left: -0%; }
}
@keyframes background4 {
  0% { margin-left: -100%; }
  70% { margin-left: -100%; }
  75% { margin-left: -0%; }
  95% { margin-left: -0%; }
  100% { margin-left: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<img id="bg1" src="http://download-wallpaper.net/images/nature-background/nature-background-24.jpg">
<img id="bg2" src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/pwQMS6f.jpg">
<img id="bg3" src="http://all4desktop.com/data_images/original/4236532-background-images.jpg">
<img id="bg4" src="http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/background-desktop-wallpaper-hd/background-desktop-wallpaper-hd-9.jpg">
```

Comment: images do not slide in or slide out as questioner want. it only appear on screen.

Comment: @AMH Ok, I'll fix that

Comment: @SHayward How's my answer?

Comment: @JamesDouglas Looks great, however at the same time as the new image slides in, I'd like the old image to slide out. Is that possible?

Comment: @SHayward Yes it is. I've updated my answer. Remember to mark my answer as accepted if you're happy with it!

Answer (score 0):

@JamesDouglas has answered to your first question. But Regarding your second question, In your JS, you have set the slide change time to "5000" milliseconds, that's why the slides are taking ages to change. Change it to 1000 milliseconds, The slides will change faster than before. Hope this helps.

```
setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);
```

Comment: I'm happy with the length of the animation; the problem is that the image takes a while to actually load on the screen, so it's blank for a second or two before the image appears. I'm not sure if that's just because the image is quite high resolution though?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code so it might be the size of the images. Just to make sure you can simply compress your images without losing the quality here: http://compressjpeg.com OR you can try different images.

Hope this helps @SHayward :)